# Talking to button values in an array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, button

I got a problem concidering talking to the value of a button. Just for you to maybe understand my target a little bit better, I will post my whole code and the sence of my 'problemcode' right here:

```
for(i=0;i<144;i++){

    if(i%12 <= 10 && i%12 >= 1 && Math.floor(i/12) >= 1 && Math.floor(i/12) <= 10) {

        window.alert(change.button+i.value);
        if(change.button+i.value==0 && change.button+i.className=='revealed') {

            change.button+(i-1).className='revealed';
            change.button+(i+1).className='revealed';
            change.button+(i-11).className='revealed';
            change.button+(i-12).className='revealed';
            change.button+(i-13).className='revealed';
            change.button+(i+11).className='revealed';
            change.button+(i+12).className='revealed';
            change.button+(i+13).className='revealed';
            alert.writeln("test");
        }
    }
}
```

So I wrote a simple Minesweeper code. Works pretty good but I wanted to improve it by revealing the area around one button if it has the value '0'. Additionally I should admit that the array has the size of 144 but I will only show 100 elements, so I have an invisible boarder.
Now again coming to the problem. I want to do a scan everytime a button got clicked. So I check the value of every button if it is 'revealed' and it's value is '0'. My problem here though is that the way I try to talk to it is wrong, but you may understand what I am trying to reach. So here is my code, I would appreachead if you might help me :)
*note ignore the dbclick, this does not work

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Einfachsweeper</title>
    <style>
        .revealed{color:blue;}
        .invisible{color:transparent}
        .fahne{background-color:blue;color:transparent;}
    </style>
    <script language="Javascript">
        feld3 = [];
        minen=12;
        feld2 = [];
        for(y=0;y<=11;y++){
            feld3[y]=[];
            for(x=0;x<=11;x++){
                feld3[y][x]=0;
            }
        }
        for(y=0;y<=11;y++){
                for(x=0;x<=11;x++){
                    //document.writeln(+feld3[y][x]+" ");
                }   
            }
        for(i=1;i<=minen;i++){
            randz=Math.random();
            randz=Math.floor(randz*100);
            randx=randz%10+1;
            randy=Math.floor(randz/10)+1;
            //document.writeln(randy + " " + randx + ",");
            if(feld3[randy][randx]==0){
                //document.writeln("test");
                feld3[randy][randx]='x';
            }
            else{
                //document.writeln("test");
                i--;
            }
        }
        for(y=1;y<=10;y++){
                for(x=1;x<=10;x++){
                    wert=0;
                    if(feld3[y][x]!='x'){
                        if(feld3[y-1][x-1]=='x'){
                            wert++;
                        }
                        if(feld3[y-1][x]=='x'){
                            wert++;
                        }
                        if(feld3[y-1][x+1]=='x'){
                            wert++;
                        }
                        if(feld3[y][x+1]=='x'){
                            wert++;
                        }
                        if(feld3[y+1][x+1]=='x'){
                            wert++;
                        }
                        if(feld3[y+1][x]=='x'){
                            wert++;
                        }
                        if(feld3[y+1][x-1]=='x'){
                            wert++;
                        }
                        if(feld3[y][x-1]=='x'){
                            wert++;
                        }
                        feld3[y][x]=wert;
                    }
                }   
            }
        i=0;
        while(i<144){
            for(y=0;y<=11;y++){
                for(x=0;x<=11;x++){
                    feld2[i]=feld3[y][x];
                    i++;
                }   
            }
        }



        document.writeln("<form method='post' name='change' action='bla.html'><table border='1'><tr>");
        for(i=0;i<144;i++){
            if(i%12<=10 && i%12>=1 && Math.floor(i/12)>=1 && Math.floor(i/12)<=10){
                document.writeln("<td><input class='invisible' type='button'  name='button"+i+"' value='"+feld2[i]+"' onDblClick='right(this)' onClick='changer(this)'></td>");
            }
            if(i%12==11){
                document.writeln("</tr><tr>");
            }
        }
        document.writeln("</tr></table>");

        function right(item){
            item.className='fahne';
            window.alert('works');
        }

        function changer(item){
            //window.alert(item.name);
            i=21;
        //  window.alert(change.button+i.value);
            /*for(i=0;i<144;i++){
                if(i%12<=10 && i%12>=1 && Math.floor(i/12)>=1 && Math.floor(i/12)<=10){
                    window.alert(change.button+i.value);
                    if(change.button+i.value==0 && change.button+i.className=='revealed'){
                        change.button+(i-1).className='revealed';
                        change.button+(i+1).className='revealed';
                        change.button+(i-11).className='revealed';
                        change.button+(i-12).className='revealed';
                        change.button+(i-13).className='revealed';
                        change.button+(i+11).className='revealed';
                        change.button+(i+12).className='revealed';
                        change.button+(i+13).className='revealed';
                        alert.writeln("test");
                    }
                }
            }*/
            if(item.which == 3){
                window.alert('right');
            }
            if(item.value=='x'){
                window.alert('You lost!');
            }
            //window.alert(item.value);
            item.className="revealed";
            //document.writeln(item);
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!--<input type='button' name='invisible' value=' ' onClick="changer()">
    <input type='button' name='test' value=' '></form>-->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

This line and the others like it have a syntax error:

```
change.button+(i-1).className='revealed';
//     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The `change` automatic global has automatic properties for each button; the names of those properties are `button0`, `button2`, etc.

So to access `button0` using `i = 0`, you use bracketed notation and string concatenation:

```
change["button" + (i-1)].className='revealed';
```

---

Your code is relying on the browser creating an automatic global variable, `change`, because you've created a `form` element with `name="change"`. It's also relying on that form object getting automatic properties for its fields because you've used `name="button0"` and such on them.

I wouldn't recommend relying on either of those things. Instead, look up the form intentionally:

```
var change = document.querySelector("form[name=change]");
```

and get the buttons from it intentionally:

```
var buttons = change.querySelectorAll("input[type=button]");
```

`buttons` will be an array of the buttons in document order. To access a button by its index in that list you'd use `buttons[i]`. So:

```
buttons[i-1].className='revealed';
```

FWIW.

Comment: If I want to do it your way, what is the value and className of the buttons?

Comment: It's the same object, so `.value` and `.className`.

Comment: Yes thats how you talk to it but what is the 'default' value if I check with e.g. writeln(button0.value); ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: So if I got you right I should be able to create a field of '0' by this: (doesn't work + sorry for formation)
` var change = document.querySelector("form[name=change]");
  var buttons = change.querySelectorAll("input[type=button]");
  document.writeln("<table border='1'><tr>");
  for(i=0;i<144;i++){
   if(i%12<=10 && i%12>=1 && Math.floor(i/12)>=1 && Math.floor(i/12)<=10){
    buttons[i].value=0;
    document.writeln("<td>'".buttons[i].value."'</td>");
   }
   if(i%12==11){
    document.writeln("</tr><tr>");
   }
  }
  document.writeln("</tr></table>");`

Comment: @FrontMobe: You can't really intermix `document.write` / `document.writeln` with accessing the DOM objects; the former is for creating the document, the latter for interacting with the document once it exists.

Comment: I can|t really follow you then. How can i get access to my buttons then. I want a field of them. The type is .html at the moment, so everytime i "document.writeln" i can just print it as a html code (e.g. button).Sorry if you think I do not have enough basics for that code, but I did all tutorials i got access to and tried my best to follow. So don't expect me to understand why you do it that way and neither what e.g. DOM is :D